# Rails 3 Post to external web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, web-services

Lets say I have a blog post that a user is creating and I want to send all of the data to an external web service as XML with a specific schema so it can be ingested into that web service.

I have been looking into the ActionDispatch::Request

And I read this [Using Ruby on Rails to POST JSON/XML data to a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340052/using-ruby-on-rails-to-post-json-xml-data-to-a-web-service) post and answer

However I got an error saying content_type was not a valid method for request. So I changed that line to call the header method and create a header for content-type with the appropriate information

Ok... so now where to go?

This is my code so far:

```
url= URI.parse('http://10.29.3.47:8080/ingest')
response = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
request.body = 'all of my xml data and schema which is far too long to type here'
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(request)}
assert_equal '201 Created', response.get_fields('Status')
```

I get an error saying that request.body is also not a valid method call, but when I look at the API the only thing matching body is "body()" which does not take arguments. So how do I pass the content of my post to the web service?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Note that using `Net::HTTP` directly is one of many options. Here are some others: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients

Answer (score 1):

You had `response = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)` instead of `request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)` and you [add](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html#method-i-add_field) headers with `add_field`.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
url= URI.parse('http://10.29.3.47:8080/ingest')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.add_field 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
request.body = 'all of my xml data and schema which is far too long to type here'
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(request)}
```