# Shortest way to send a POST call to a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, post

What's the shortest/simplest way to send a POST call to an external URL from a Rails app?

I need to send a POST request to a URL like this:

```
http://api.example.com/aff?id=12345&sub=123456
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good example: [How do I post XML to RESTFUL Web Service using Net::HTTP::Post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629632/ruby-posting-xml-to-restful-web-service-using-nethttppost)

```
url = URI.parse('http://api.example.com/aff?id=12345&sub=123456')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(request)}
```